# jQuery Superfish Menu on Wordpress doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, superfish

I working on a jQuery 'Superfish' dropdown menu (Wordpress). I use the latest version of superfish and wordpress. The problem is, superfish makes my menu invisible... i see nothing of my menu...

**functions.php**

```
//Register Superfish
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'superfish_libs' );  
function superfish_libs()  
{  
    // Register each script, setting appropriate dependencies  
    wp_register_script('hoverintent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/superfish-js/hoverIntent.js');  
    wp_register_script('bgiframe',    get_template_directory_uri() . '/superfish-js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js');  
    wp_register_script('superfish',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/superfish-js/superfish.js', array( 'jquery', 'hoverintent', 'bgiframe' ));  
    wp_register_script('supersubs',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/superfish-js/supersubs.js', array( 'superfish' ));  

    // Enqueue supersubs, we don't need to enqueue any others in this case, as the dependencies take care of it for us  
    wp_enqueue_script('supersubs'); 

    // Register each style, setting appropriate dependencies 
    wp_register_style('superfishbase',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/superfish-css/superfish.css');
    wp_register_style('superfishvert',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/superfish-css/superfish-vertical.css', array( 'superfishbase' )); 
    wp_register_style('superfishnavbar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/superfish-css/superfish-navbar.css', array( 'superfishvert' )); 

    // Enqueue superfishnavbar, we don't need to enqueue any others in this case either, as the dependencies take care of it  
    wp_enqueue_style('superfishnavbar');  
}

//Register jQuery 1.1.3
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

wp_deregister_script('jquery');
if(!is_admin()) { 
     wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.1.3.js');
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

**header.php**

```
<div id="wrapper-mainnav">

            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'mainnav', 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu')); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="right"></div>

            <br class="clearer">

            <div class="bottom"></div>

        </div><!--wrapper-mainnav-->
```

Please help, i can't find the fault... please tell me, if you need more information...

Comment: just try putting the scripts into footer and make sure your menu is there and displaying fine before the code. and jQuery 1.1.3 is dated back to the beginning of time.

Comment: i added it, but i have the same problem. i updatet jquery: `wp_deregister_script('jquery');
if(!is_admin()) { 
     wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js');
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
` if i remove the sf-menu class, it works

Comment: are you trying to change the back-end of wordpress menu?

Comment: thanks @VictorWeng a stupid fault. i forgot to define the menu in the backend. now it works...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [**don't dequeue WordPress bundled jQuery**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45440).

Seems a bit hard to add the class `sf-menu` to the `<ul>` container. It's being applied to the upper `<div>`.
I tried many variations of arguments in `wp_nav_menu` to no avail.

A simple solution is to change it manually

```
$mainnav = wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'mainnav', 'echo' => false );
echo str_replace( '<ul>', '<ul class="sf-menu">', $mainnav );
```